# python - how to get page number as a variable

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i was trying to scrap some movie reviews and ratings, and im trying to end this code if there's no more reviews&ratings.

```
page = 1  #'variable' page
blankList = []
while True:
    url = "http://movie.naver.com/movie/bi/mi/pointWriteFormList.nhn?code=99715&type=after&isActualPointWriteExecute=false&isMileageSubscriptionAlready=false&isMileageSubscriptionReject=false&page={}".format(page) 
    res = requests.get(url)
    bs = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
    valueList = bs.findAll("input",{'value':"{}"}).format(str(page))

    ###the upper code won't work when 'variable page' is bigger than 'maximum page'. if so, it returns blank List.

    page = page + 1
    score_result = bs.find("div", {'class': 'score_result'})
    for review_one in score_result.findAll('li'):
        score = int(review_one.find("div", {'class': 'star_score'}).find('em').text)
        reple = review_one.find('div',{'class': 'score_reple'}).find('p')
        for span in reple.findAll('span'):
            span.extract()
        reple = reple.text
        print("reple: {}, score: {}".format(reple, score))

    if (valueList == blankList):
        break
```

so what i'm having problem is kinda simple. you'll probably know that this part won't work

```
valueList = bs.findAll("input",{'value':"{}"}).format(str(page))
```

lets say the maximum page number is 100, and when i input 20 in `variable` page,

```
url = "http://movie.naver.com/movie/bi/mi/pointWriteFormList.nhn?code=99715&type=after&isActualPointWriteExecute=false&isMileageSubscriptionAlready=false&isMileageSubscriptionReject=false&page={}".format(page)
```

this part has no problem, and when i try to input 20 in here(real page number)

```
valueList = bs.findAll("input",{'value':"{}"}).format(str(page))
```

it will return this List.

```
['input id="page" name="page" type="hidden" value="20"/>]
```

but when i try to input 200 (in both of them)
first code won't show an error but

```
valueList = bs.findAll("input",{'value':"{}"}).format(str(page))
```

it returns blank list, cuz there is no page number 200.

---

what i need is:

1. extract the value of `value` in this list, and set it as a variable. 
   in this list, what i need is 87.

   ['input id="page" name="page" type="hidden" value="87"/>]

or

2. is there any possible way to put variable in `findAll` function?

   - this list pops out when i run this code
     `bs.findAll("input")`:

     > > > ['input type="hidden" name="onlyActualPointYn" id="onlyActualPointYn" value="N">, 'input type="hidden" name="movieCode" id="movieCode" value="99715">, 'input type="hidden" name="order" id="order" value="sympathyScore">, 'input type="hidden" name="page" id="page" value="75">, 'input type="hidden" name="point" id="point" value="0">]

Answer (score 0):

Please change the line as mentioned below,

```
valueList = bs.findAll("input",{'value':"{}".format(str(page))})
```

This program doesn't exits because every page number is a valid one for this url. If you five 777777777 , its also a valid page number. You can try it in browser.

Output:

```
reple: 이영화 시사회에서 봤는데 15세는 진짜 말이 안된다. 그래도 엄청 재밌습니다.  , score: 10
```